# How to forward Screen Capture in iOS 11 Control Center to your App?

Tags: ios, ios11, teamviewer, replaykit

I saw that TeamViewer allows iOS Screen Capturing by leveraging the Screen Recorder feature from the Control Center in iOS 11. As seen here: [image: teamviewer example screen]

How is that possible? I checked out the ReplayKit, but couldn't find any feature that would hook up to the Control Center like that.

Comment: `Broadcast Upload Extension` with the help of this, I can list my app in Control Center, like TEAM VIEWER. After that, If I press START BROADCAST, Screen Record will start within 3 seconds. Upto this working fine. If I try to STOP the record by clicking RED COLOR STATUS BAR, then, Record will not save in camera roll.

This only doubt I am having. How to save recordings in my camera roll and in my app? Can u guide me?

Comment: Can u help me on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a `Broadcast Upload Extension` to your app.

(In Xcode, File > New Target, select "Broadcast Upload Extension")

Once the extension is installed (alongside your app), a force-touch on the screen recording icon in control center will give the option of using your broadcast extension, instead of the default ("Camera Roll").

There is very little documentation on iOS Screen Recording right now. But this WWDC video talks about it at a high level:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/

Comment: `Broadcast Upload Extension` with the help of this, I can list my app in Control Center, like TEAM VIEWER. After that, If I press START BROADCAST, Screen Record will start within 3 seconds. Upto this working fine. If I try to STOP the record by clicking RED COLOR STATUS BAR, then, Record will not save in camera roll.

This only doubt I am having. How to save recordings in my camera roll and in my app? Can u guide me?

Comment: @McDonal_11 better to ask a new question

Comment: can you help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485367/screen-recording-when-my-ios-app-is-in-background-with-replaykit